# Assume $x_n>0$,$x_n+\dfrac{4}{x_{n+1}^2}<3.$ Prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n$ exists and evaluate it.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

#### My Solution

Notice that $$x_n+\dfrac{4}{x_{n+1}^2}<3=3\sqrt[3]{\frac{x_n}{2}\cdot\frac{x_n}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{x_n^2}}\leq \frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{4}{x_n^2}=x_n+\frac{4}{x_n^2}.$$
This shows that
$$x_{n+1}>x_n.\tag1$$
Moreover $$x_n<3-\frac{4}{x_{n+1}^2}<3.\tag2$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, according to the monotone convergence theorem, $x_n$ is convergent,namely,$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n$ exists, whom we denote as $L$.

Since $$x_n+\dfrac{4}{x_{n+1}^2}<3,$$ taking the limits,we obtain $$L+\frac{4}{L^2}\leq 3. \tag3$$
Similarily, since $$x_n+\dfrac{4}{x_{n}^2}\geq 3,$$ taking the limits,we obtain $$L+\frac{4}{L^2}\geq 3. \tag4$$
From $(3)$ and $(4)$, we obtain $$L+\frac{4}{L^2}=3.$$
Thus, we can solve to have $$L=2.$$
The other root $L=-1$ contradicts $x_n>0,$ which implies $L \geq 0$.

**Please correct me if I'm wrong. Hope to see other solutions.**

Comment: Why does $x_n+\dfrac{4}{x_{n}^2}\geq 3$ ?

Comment: @lhf See first line. AM-GM inequality...

Comment: It's all correct.